# Confused with the return result of TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I wanted to learn more about NLP. I came across this piece of code. But I was confused about the outcome of `TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform` when the result is printed. I am familiar with what tfidf is but I could not understand what the numbers mean.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import os
import io
import string
import requests
import csv
import nltk
from zipfile import ZipFile

sess = tf.Session()

batch_size = 100
max_features = 1000

save_file_name = os.path.join('smsspamcollection', 'SMSSpamCollection.csv')
if os.path.isfile(save_file_name):
    text_data = []
    with open(save_file_name, 'r') as temp_output_file:
        reader = csv.reader(temp_output_file)
        for row in reader:
            text_data.append(row)

else:
    zip_url = 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00228/smsspamcollection.zip'
    r = requests.get(zip_url)
    z = ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
    file = z.read('SMSSpamCollection')

    # Format data 
    text_data = file.decode()
    text_data = text_data.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
    text_data = text_data.decode().split('\n')
    text_data = [x.split('\t') for x in text_data if len(x) >= 1]

    # And write to csv 
    with open(save_file_name, 'w') as temp_output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(temp_output_file)
        writer.writerows(text_data)

texts = [x[1] for x in text_data]
target = [x[0] for x in text_data]
target = [1 if x == 'spam' else 0 for x in target]

# Normalize the text
texts = [x.lower() for x in texts]  # lower
texts = [''.join(c for c in x if c not in string.punctuation) for x in texts]  # remove punctuation
texts = [''.join(c for c in x if c not in '0123456789') for x in texts]  # remove numbers
texts = [' '.join(x.split()) for x in texts]  # trim extra whitespace


def tokenizer(text):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    return words


tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer, stop_words='english', max_features=max_features)
sparse_tfidf_texts = tfidf.fit_transform(texts)
print(sparse_tfidf_texts)
```

And the output is:

> (0, 630)  0.37172623140154337   (0, 160)  0.36805562944957004   (0,
> 38)   0.3613966215413548   (0, 545)   0.2561101665717327   (0,
> 326)  0.2645280991765623   (0, 967)   0.3277447602873963   (0,
> 421)  0.3896274380321477   (0, 227)   0.28102915589024796   (0,
> 323)  0.22032541100275282   (0, 922)  0.2709848154866997   (1,
> 577)  0.4007895093299793   (1, 425)   0.5970064521899725   (1,
> 943)  0.6310763941180291   (1, 878)   0.29102173465492637   (2,
> 282)  0.1771481430848552   (2, 243)   0.5517018054305785   (2,
> 955)  0.2920174942032025   (2, 138)   0.30143666813167863   (2,
> 946)  0.2269933441326121   (2, 165)   0.3051095293405041   (2,
> 268)  0.2820392223588522   (2, 780)   0.24119626642264894   (2,
> 823)  0.1890454397278538   (2, 674)   0.256251970757827   (2,
> 874)  0.19343834015314287   : :   (5569, 648) 0.24171652492226922
> (5569, 123)   0.23011909339432202   (5569, 957)   0.24817919217662862
> (5569, 549)   0.28583789844730134   (5569, 863)   0.3026729783085827
> (5569, 844)   0.20228305447951195   (5569, 146)   0.2514415602877767
> (5569, 595)   0.2463259875380789   (5569, 511)    0.3091904754885042
> (5569, 230)   0.2872728684768659   (5569, 638)    0.34151390143548765
> (5569, 83)    0.3464271621701711   (5570, 370)    0.4199910200421362
> (5570, 46)    0.48234172093857797   (5570, 317)   0.4171646676697801
> (5570, 281)   0.6456993475093024   (5572, 282)    0.25540827228532487
> (5572, 385)   0.36945842040023935   (5572, 448)   0.25540827228532487
> (5572, 931)   0.3031800542518209   (5572, 192)    0.29866989620926737
> (5572, 303)   0.43990016711221736   (5572, 87)    0.45211284173737176
> (5572, 332)   0.3924202767503492   (5573, 866)    1.0

I would be more than happy if someone can explain about the output.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Note that you are printing a sparse matrix so the output looks different compared to printing a standard dense matrix. See below the main components:

- The tuple represents: `(document_id, token_id)`
- The value following the tuple represents the tf-idf score of a given token in a given document
- The tuples that are not there have a tf-idf score of 0

If you want to find what token the `token_id` corresponds to, check the `get_feature_names` method.

Comment: Everything is as clear as a crystal now. That was intuitive and now it makes a lot of sense. Thanks !

Comment: It's so weird that this is not properly documented. Thank you.